# Interpolate style in angular won't work (Ionic 5)

Tags: angular, ionic5

I'm trying this in Ionic 5 and it works:

```
<ion-content style="--background: yellow;">
```

However I want to change the color dinamically. I've tried this with no success:

```
<ion-content [ngStyle]="{'--background': backgroundColor}">
```

I can't find the mistake.

Comment: What kind of error you're getting? I can't find any mistake in that, can you fork your project on a stackblitz perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NgStyle` does not support css variables.
It's a "known" limitation and it's been for quite a while:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9343

There are workarounds, however, even if somewhat ugly. My preferred is this:

```
<ion-content [attr.style]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('--background: ' + backgroundColor)">
```

```js
// you will need a DomSanitizer instance in your component
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

Comment: You are correct, that worked perfectly - I had no idea about it. Thanks.